# Why vector bundles are defined differently in algebraic geometry and topology?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, math-history

Over schemes, we can define

1. locally free sheaves;
2. vector bundles associated to a quasi-coherent sheaf ([Stacks Project](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01M1)).

These notions seem to be dual to each other. It is easy to see on $\mathrm{Spec}(k)$ for a field, a locally free sheaf is a vector space $V$, and the vector bundle associated to the quasi-coherent sheaf $V$ is $V^*$.

[Lemma 27.6.3](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/062N) shows an anti-equivalence between the category of vector bundles and the category of quasi-coherent sheaves.

However topologically, vector bundles are defined first and its associated locally free sheaf is the sheaf of sections. This association is covariant rather than contravariant.

I wonder why algebraic geometers prefer this definition of vector bundles. Are there any conceptual or historical reasons behind this?

Comment: I would say one basis reason is sheaf cohomology (although I am not saying that is not used in topology, I would say it is used a lot more often in AG). 

Let $E$ be a vector bundle over a lets say smooth complex algebraic variety $X$.

The fact that $H^{i}(E,X)$ is a finite dimensional complex vector space is surprising and useful. 

If you have a smooth manifold then these won't be finite dimensional so it is less clear what to do with them (although there are certainly people who do that).